# Invoking columns and filters panel programatically

Tags: material-ui

Is there a way to programatically open and close the ColumnsPanel and FilterPanel in XGrid/DataGrid? My Toolbar needs state so I am building it independently to the DataGrid (not using the components interface).

Comment: Show us your code, preferably on Codesandbox.

Comment: @NearHuscarl I am building my own toolbar and I want to have my own "Columns" and "Filters" buttons (https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/demo/). What i am looking for are methods to open the "filters" and "columns" panels in the same way as GridColumnsToolbarButton and GridFilterToolbarButton do.